# User object location in iOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a user object, which I would like to store the currently logged in user for, as well as have functions that will allow the user to do things, such as logout, login, etc.

Following various tutorials and plenty of posts on here, I've come up with some code that works well so far when logging in via the login page. Here is that code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

// define the protocol for using this class
protocol LoginProtocol {
    func didRecieveLoginResponse(status: Bool, message: String?)
}

class User : APIControllerProtocol {
  var delegate: LoginProtocol
  var username: String?
  var company: String?
  var auth_token: String?
  // more properties here

  // initiate the class, must have a delegate as per the protocol
  init(delegate: LoginProtocol, username: String?, school: String?) {
    self.delegate = delegate
    if(username != nil) {
        self.username = username
        self.company = company

    }
  }

  // login using the API
  func login(password: String) {
    print("Logging in as " + username! + " - " + company!)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    let api = APIController(delegate: self)
    var postFields = [String: String]()
    postFields["username"] = username
    postFields["password"] = password
    postFields["company"] = company
    api.request("login",postData: postFields)
  }

  // API results were received, log in the user if appropriate
  func didRecieveAPIResults(originalRequest: String,apiResponse: APIResponse) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if(apiResponse.status == true) {
            self.auth_token = details["auth_token"]
            // more properties here
            self.save_to_user_defaults()
            self.delegate.didRecieveLoginResponse(true, message:nil )
        } else {
            self.delegate.didRecieveLoginResponse(false, message:apiResponse.message )
        }
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    })
  }

  // save the properties to user defaults
  func save_to_user_defaults() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(self.username, forKey: "username")
    defaults.setObject(self.company, forKey: "company")
    defaults.setObject(self.auth_token, forKey: "auth_token")
    // more properties here
  }

  // load the properties from user defaults
  func load_from_user_defaults() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    self.username = defaults.objectForKey("username") as? String
    self.company = defaults.objectForKey("company") as? String
    self.auth_token = defaults.objectForKey("auth_token") as? String
    // more properties here
  }
}
```

The next stage for me is logging in the user via NSUserDefaults - my plan to do this is via something like this:

```
let user = User()
user.load_from_user_defaults()
```

However I'm not quite sure:

- Whether I'm on the right track (this is my first complete swift app)
- If I am, where to put the above 2 lines of code (perhaps the app delegate?), such that when the app is opened, the user in NSUserDefaults (if there is one) is logged back in
- How to allow the rest of the app access to the user (I'd like to be able to be able to reference user data in my view controllers, e.g. let pointsLabel.text = users.points)

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope, my answer will help in improving your app:

1. `NSUserDefaults` is not secure, it can be easily opened and read, both on device & to a Mac. So user defaults is a good place for preferences and config info, however it's not a good for  sensitive information, like passwords. Check the [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password) for more details
2. Yes, it should be in app delegate. Load the user data and present the view accordingly.
3. Either you can pass user data to view controller or just read from persistent storage. Depends upon your requirement.

Comment: Thank you Anni, that's very useful indeed! Presumably, things like the username are fine in NSUserDefaults, but something like an authentication token should go in the keychain then?

Comment: Yes, you can store non-sensitive info(user name is also fine) in NSUserDefaults.